# Is there a difference in the output (final layer) between NN and CNN?

Tags: matlab, classification, multiclass-classification, conv-neural-network

In the case of multiclass classification, if the number of classes are `N`, then a NN has `N` output nodes. However, for binary classification using NN, the output node is only one.

**Confusion:** For binary classification using CNN with integer valued labels (0/1 or 1/2), would the number of output nodes be 2? Or with one-hot encoding scheme 0-0, 0-1,1-0 and 1-1 the number of output nodes would be 2 otherwise 1 output node.

This confusion also comes from the implementation syntax. In the code below using CNN, for binary classification I have to mention `numClasses =2` when the classes are integer valued 0/1 or 1/2. Does that mean that there are 2 output nodes?  Please correct me where wrong.

```
inputSize = [28 28 1];
numClasses = 2;

layers = [
    imageInputLayer(inputSize)
    convolution2dLayer(5,20)
    batchNormalizationLayer
    reluLayer
    fullyConnectedLayer(numClasses)
    softmaxLayer
    classificationLayer];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation syntax is correct. But for binary classification use just sigmoid activation instead of softmax with just one node for the last layer.

When sigmoid is used, then number of output nodes is 1 and one hot encoding is not used. 
Output of sigmoid is probability and if probability is greater 0.5 output class is class 1 
and otherwise class 2.

When softmax is used, then number of output nodes is 2 and one hot encoding is required.
Both output nodes represents probabilities of each respective class.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Just a clarification though, if I followed you correctly (1) for binary classification using conv NN, if `numclasses = 2` then I would use `softmax`; for the same binary classification if `numclasses=1` then I should use `sigmoid` Is that right? (2) does the choice of sigmoid and softmax totally depend on the designer? OR is there a difference in performance hence a preference?

Comment: (1) No numclasses is same i.e.2 in both activations. Outputs of the softmax are probabilities and sum of these probabilities is 1. So in case of binary classification, probability of one output node can be calculated by subtracting from 1 the probability of other node and therefore one node becomes redundant. So in case of binary classification sigmoid activation is preferred as it directly outputs a probability which can be assigned to a class and probability of other class can be calculated by subtracting from 1.

Comment: (2) As softmax has two output node against one for sigmoid, for binary classification. Therefore NN with softmax has more weight biases to be trained. Performance wise both NN can be same but for the one with softmax more training time (epoch) is required.